# Arial Font Missing using Flash CS4

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, flash-cs4, flash-8

I have a (old) Flash Document ".fla" file created in Flash 8.
It just has a static textbox with "Hello World"(many more text boxes) in it .
(just for the question. )
The font set is **Arial 12pt Bold**  (thr. the Flash 8 IDE).

When i open the same file in Flash CS4 IDE i get the Missing Font Dialog and then it
asks to Map "Arial" to another font.

When i map missing "Arial" to "Arial" with style "Regular"..all Arial text boxes change to 
"Regular",even the one with "Bold" face.  I even installed Arial font again but found the same problem?

**Edit: Added  Link to the sample file**
http://www.mediafire.com/file/mjz2uhwnjmt/testFont.fla

Created in flash 8 .with static text boxes.
When open in Flash CS4 give missing font mapping dialog

Any one has any clues on how to fix this?
Is anything done incorrectly or is it a kind of bug in Flash CS4.

thx
Amit

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it cannot match "ariel" with "Ariel", if you have Flash 8 still, maybe just change all ariel to something different, open it in Flash CS4 again, and change it back to Ariel.

Seems rather odd to be honest.